# nmap scanning IP Addresses that aren't an A record for the scanned hostname

Tags: dns, nmap

I'm scanning for transparent proxies/MiTM and I found this while running a scan against *cn.pool.ntp.org*:

```
joe@APP05:~$ dig cn.pool.ntp.org

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> cn.pool.ntp.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 42856
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cn.pool.ntp.org.               IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
cn.pool.ntp.org.        150     IN      A       5.79.108.34
cn.pool.ntp.org.        150     IN      A       85.199.214.100

;; Query time: 457 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Jul 06 09:13:11 EDT 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 65

joe@APP05:~$ nmap -sT cn.pool.ntp.org -p 80

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-07-06 09:09 EDT
Nmap scan report for cn.pool.ntp.org (202.100.138.68)
Host is up (0.23s latency).
Other addresses for cn.pool.ntp.org (not scanned): 120.25.115.19 202.112.10.37
rDNS record for 202.100.138.68: cache2.qhxnptt.net.cn
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.46 seconds
```

Aside from the indicator of a transparent proxy with the open TCP port 80, why did nmap scan 202.100.138.68 and not scan 120.25.115.19 and 202.112.10.37 when the A records for *cn.pool.ntp.org* were 5.79.108.34 and 85.199.214.100?

Where did those 3 IP addresses come from?  I know that the A records for *cn.pool.ntp.org* change constantly for load-balancing, availability, etc but that is not the case in this scenario - the A records remained the same.  The system that ran both of these commands only knows of a single resolver via /etc/resolv.conf (1.1.1.1).

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZxFh3pFKPy/ shows the current DNS data with a direct query of Google DNS.  Note that this is a **dynamic address** managed by the NTP pool system, there's no guarantee those IPs are the *only* ones you'll get back, they can change without notice.

Comment: I understand the pool's A records change constantly but they didn't change between running the dig and the nmap shown above... so why would nmap pull 3 different IP addresses for the hostname?  That's what I'm trying to determine.